# Async programming, why doesn't the code get executed

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm quite new to async programming, but I need it badly inside on of our applications.

I'm just trying something inside a Console Application but it doesn't seem to work. I'm aware that a Console Application doesn't support async out of the box as there isn't a main thread like a UI thread in a WinForms Application.

Anyway, here's what I'm trying:

I have an async method which contains the following logic:

```
public static async Task MainAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("This method is being executed.");

    await Task.Delay(3000);

    Console.WriteLine("Async method has finished.");
}
```

Now, I want to execute this code from a Console Application which I'm doing like this, to make it work:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task t = MainAsync();
    t.Wait();
}
```

So far no problem, them application is executed as it's supposed to.
First write a single string, then wait 3 seconds, then prints a second line, and all that in an async way.

Now, I've created a wrapper around my code which looks like the following:

```
public static class AsynchronousContext 
{
    public static void Run(Task task)
    {
        task.Wait();
    }
}
```

So, now my main method can be changed to:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AsynchronousContext.Run(MainAsync());
}
```

Which does the same as the sample above.

Now, I've tried to create an overload on the `Run` method in which I passes an `Action`.

```
public static void Run(Action action)
{
    new TaskFactory().StartNew(action).Wait();
}
```

However, when I change my main method call to:

```
AsynchronousContext.Run(() => MainAsync());
```

The code isn't working anymore. I get the first line and than a line that says that the application can be finished by clicking a key, in order words, the main thread finished before the await.

I've tried the following also, but the only think I got was a black console application without contents:

```
public static void Run(Action action)
    {
        var task = new Task(action);
        task.Wait();
    }
```

Anyone who can explain as simple as possible what's happening here?

Comment: Notice that the Task you create in your `Run(Action...` function just calls the action? The difference is that before you used the `Task` you get back from this action (`MainAsync()`) and **wait** for it ... this new task you create with `TaskFactory...` does **not** - so of course it will finish as soon as it started the thread ....

Comment: But I create it with a simple task from an action it isn't working either.

Comment: I think you have to work on your understanding of tasks/threads - yeah you create it - but you don't wait for the stuff `MainAsync` is doing to finish - you just watch till it is created and then say *fine - it's on it's way - let's move on*

Comment: I definitely need some training on async programming. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MainAsync` returns a `Task`.  You are passing this to `StartNew` as an `Action`, so there is no way for it to wait for it to finish.

In addition, there is no overload to `StartNew` that would accept a function that returns a `Task`, so `StartNew` has no way of waiting for it to finish either.

`Task.Run` is generally better suited to this, presuming you want to run your work on a thread pool thread. You can read the pitfalls of `StartNew` in [this blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). It has an overload that accepts a `Func<Task>`:

```
public static void Run(Func<Task> createTask)
{
    Task.Run(createTask).Wait();
}
```

I assume this code is only to demonstrate the principles, however - you wouldn't ordinarily want to call `Wait()` as this will block.

Comment: Ok. I think I get it, an Action doesn't return a Task so cannot be awaited. Is that correct? But why doesn't it work then if I create a Task from my Action and wait for that task to finish?

Comment: Because your `Action` itself returns a `Task`.  There's nothing available for any of your code to wait for that *inner* task to finish.  As far as the consuming code is concerned, it finishes executing almost immediately (it returns at `await Task.Delay...`).

Comment: Do you mean that I cannot simple pass in an action as I was trying to do? No problem if it isn't possible, but I just want to know it :-)

Comment: I've just tried something and I do believe it's possible with this code: `new Task(async () => await action).Wait();`

Comment: It's possible to pass a *synchronous* function as an `Action`. You cannot pass an *asynchronous* function and expect to be able to wait for it to complete.

Comment: That is possible provided `action` in that context is actually `Func<Task>` or similar.  You can't `await` an `Action`.

Comment: I've just tried and it seems that I can await a Task<Action> can't I? :)